# My Sign In XML Layout page is not displaying certain fields for Firebases "Email" and "Password" Auth

Tags: javascript, android, xml, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have changed the Gradles and they **both work correctly** for this layout to work with the existing Firebase SDK's etc. I just cannot seem to fit everything in my XML like in this example picture. Is there something I'm missing in my grade or XML??

```js
< RelativeLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: id = "@+id/main_layout"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: background = "@color/grey_100"
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: weightSum = "4" >

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/imageView"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
app: srcCompat = "@drawable/new_green_360" / >

  <
  ProgressBar
android: id = "@+id/progressBar"
style = "?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_centerVertical = "true"
android: indeterminate = "true"
android: visibility = "gone" / >



  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: layout_weight = "3"
android: gravity = "center_horizontal"
android: orientation = "vertical" >

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/icon"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: contentDescription = "@string/desc_firebase_lockup"
android: src = "@drawable/firebase_lockup_400" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/title_text"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_marginBottom = "@dimen/title_bottom_margin"
android: text = "@string/emailpassword_title_text"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/status"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
android: text = "@string/signed_out" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/detail"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
tools: text = "Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" / >

  <
  /RelativeLayout>


  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: background = "@color/grey_300"
android: gravity = "center_vertical" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_email"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_email"
android: inputType = "textEmailAddress" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_password"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_password"
android: inputType = "textPassword" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_below = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_sign_in_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/sign_in"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_create_account_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/create_account"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/signed_in_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_centerInParent = "true"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp"
android: visibility = "gone"
android: weightSum = "2.0" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/sign_out_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/sign_out"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/verify_email_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/verify_email"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton" / >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  /RelativeLayout>

  <
  com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android: id = "@+id/loginButton"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "18dp"
android: layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_marginBottom = "75dp"
android: paddingBottom = "10dp"
android: paddingTop = "10dp" / >

  <
  />
```

Gradle:

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.transcendencetech.juliospizzaprototype"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Is the picture above your layout?

Comment: It's what I want the layout to look like. The XML is a bit of a mess. I'll clean that up.

Comment: Then please post your actual layout.